# multiplicative function - gcd - lcm

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, multiplicative-function

How can I show if $f$ is multiplicative and $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, that this implies that $f (\text{gcd} (x,y)) * f ( \text{lcm} (x,y)) = f(x)*f(y)$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you trying to show $\text{gcd} (x,y)* \text{lcm} (x,y)=xy$

Comment: Rather will it help if i prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is multiplicative, it is only necessary to show this for prime powers.  So let $p$ be a prime and let $i,j$ be non-negative integers and take $x=p^i$ and $y=p^j$.  We know that $\gcd(x,y)=\min(x,y)$ and $\textrm{lcm}(x,y)=\max(x,y)$, so $f (\text{gcd}(x,y)) \cdot f (\text{lcm} (x,y)) = f(x)\cdot f(y)$ follows immediately.  Therefore, the result holds for all positive integer values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Isn't $\text{gcd}(x,y) = \text {min} (x,y)$ and lcm$(x,y) = \text{max}(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes, that is true, but I am referring to the case when $x = p^{i}$ and $y = p^{j}$ you mentioned in your proof ..

Comment: @Tithus248 Ah, I see what you mean.  Yes, that was a typo.  Corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much! The proof is now clear to me!

Comment: @reuns which values of $x$ and $y$ do you think the statements fail for?

Comment: none sorry I should have read more carefully